# Как декодировать url-encoded в кириллицу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Как на Python декодировать url в формате %D1%C0%C9%D2.%D0%D4 в кириллицу сайт.рф?
Через

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
url = unquote(url)
```

не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что это было закодировано в `cp1251`, а не как обычно в `utf-8`:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

print(unquote('%D1%C0%C9%D2.%D0%D4', 'cp1251'))
# САЙТ.РФ
```

Comment: Надо наоборот из %D1%C0%C9%D2.%D0%D4 сделать сайт.рф

Comment: @OlegGlazunov, домены не кодируются в такой вид и у них используется кодирование в idna. Но я вас понял.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось )

Comment: @OlegGlazunov, ок, раз помогло, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)