# Как использовать кириллицу в URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib

Есть учебная задачка на Python, которая случайно прыгает по страницам англоязычной википедии:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

pages = set()
def getLinks(pageUrl):
    global pages
    
    html = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org{}'.format(pageUrl))
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for link in bs.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^(/wiki/)')):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                #We have encountered a new page
                newPage = link.attrs['href']
                print(newPage)
                pages.add(newPage)
                getLinks(newPage)
getLinks('')
```

Всё прекрасно работает. Но если я попытаюсь в качестве базового URL использовать русскоязычную вики:

```
html = urlopen('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница{}'.format(pageUrl))
```

то выдаётся сообщение об ошибке: UnicodeEncodeError:

*'ascii' codec can't encode characters*

Ветку

[Как декодировать url-encoded в кириллицу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095477/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-url-encoded-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

я читал. Там проблема другая:

1. Преобразовать URL -> cp1251
2. Мне наоборот : utf8 -> URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше запрашивать страницы модно-современно через `requests`, он с кодировками сам разберётся, и `BS` тоже разберётся, если ему `content` страницы отдать, а печатать потом в "человеческом" виде `URL`-и можно через `unquote`:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote
...
html = requests.get('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница{}'.format(pageUrl)).content
...
print(unquote(newPage))
```

Остальной код не менялся.

Пример вывода:

```
/wiki/Википедия:Патрулирование
/wiki/Файл:Wiki_letter_w_dashed.svg
/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Файл:Wiki_letter_w_dashed.svg
/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Файл:Wiki_letter_w_dashed.svg
/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Файл:Wiki_letter_w_dashed.svg
/wiki/Заглавная_страница
/wiki/Служебная:Поиск/Заглавная_страница/wiki/Заглавная_страница
...
```

Comment: Ваш метод тоже сработал. Мне кажется, он более наглядный.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [quote](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) для замены кириллицы

В `url` тогда будет такая строка:

```
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0
```

Пример:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen


uri = 'Заглавная_страница'
pageUrl = ''
url = 'http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}{}'.format(quote(uri, 'utf-8'), pageUrl)
print(url)

html = urlopen(url)
print(html)
```

Comment: Я так тоже, кстати, пробовал, но там дальше какие-то траблы вылезали. Но может автору вопроса этого и достаточно будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я бы сразу использовал `requests`, чтобы минимизировать дальнейшие проблемы :) Например, `urlopen` не умеет в редиректы, в отличии от `requests` и там могут быть, и другие проблемы

Comment: Всё получилось. только не сразу разобрался, откуда импортировать *quote(...)*  И при печати траектории надо использовать *unquote(..)*.

Comment: @Sergey, пожалуйста :)